# How to publish a static web site to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, publish

My CI pipeline generates a static HTML website via Asciidoctor. I would like to upload it to SharePoint (Office 365 edition) to be served as content rather that stored document and to be indexed for searches.

I'm completely new to SharePoint but following some tutorials, I created a SharePoint publishing site and uploaded my page to it. However, the page is just stored as a document rather than being rendered.

I also found few articles pointing to "SharePoint web pack" but nothing specific on how to use and what they do.

Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Alessandro

Comment: I've been struggling with this same thing.  Jazzy exports Swift documentation in the form of a static website from our iOS apps.  I played around with hosting these on bitbucket, but static sites on bitbucket are publicly accessible, even if the repo is private.  Had a long tech session with Microsoft support, they are now transferring me to their 'hosting' team, very low expectations at this point.  AWS S3 is likely our only option at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback provided [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c9d11521-9230-4565-9b55-13b768a45ec0/how-to-publish-a-static-web-site-via-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneral), the above is not possible.

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but here is the correct answer for modern sites with SharePoint Online.

You can share a web page by naming it with `.aspx` and putting into a document library. However, there are some caveats, active scripting must be turned on for the site and you may need to upload the aspx file(s) to your OneDrive for business first and then using the web interface to `move` the file(s) to the desired SharePoint site.